# Efficient mechanism to retrieve rownum

Tags: oracle

A quick one here. So I read about rownum around the web and am trying to see
which way to call it is best since based on SQL Optimizer both approach shows
no difference.

```
select count(distinct BCC || '~' || BN) BCCN 
from LINK_TBL 
where AN = 'abcdefg' 
and BR = 1 
and rownum <= 5;
```

or

```
select count(distinct BCCN)
from (
select BCC||'~'|| BN BCCN 
from LINK_TBL 
where AN = 'abcdefg' and BR = '1'
)
where rownum <= 5;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The optimizer can choose to solve / reorganise your query as it sees fit, as long as it provides the right results. If you check the explain plan, you may find them identical.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I analyzed this more last night and input from @Allan, they're indeed identical. I'm new to this stuff, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you're missing is the significance of using `order by` when using `rownum`.  The two queries you posted are functionally equivalent. However, the following two queries are not:

```
select count(distinct BCC || '~' || BN) BCCN 
from LINK_TBL 
where AN = 'abcdefg' 
and BR = 1 
and rownum <= 5
order by BCC || '~' || BN;

select count(distinct BCCN)
from (
select BCC||'~'|| BN BCCN 
from LINK_TBL 
where AN = 'abcdefg' and BR = '1'
order by BCC || '~' || BN
)
where rownum <= 5;
```

The difference is that the first query gets all of the rows in the specified order, then takes the first 5 rows and the second query any gets 5 rows then sorts only those 5.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This helps a lot but the order by isn't necessary for my usage on this one. But this adds up to my learning a lot.